# Where can we get Resources for vertica DB?

Tags: vertica

Can i find any resources like *PDF* or *User Guide* for learning vertica DB?

As i am beginner in vertica, also I am looking for the performance factor which affects while loading the data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the documentation is [posted publicly on my.vertica.com](https://my.vertica.com/docs/latest/HTML/index.htm).  Data-load performance depends on many factors; you should probably start with [Bulk-Loading Data](https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/BulkLoadCOPY/BulkLoadingData.htm) and then review the many [COPY parameters](https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPY/Parameters.htm).  For a general beginner introduction to Vertica, see [Getting Started](https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/GettingStartedGuide/Other/GettingStartedGuide.htm).

Comment: Thank you. I am going through the documentation from vertica official site. I am trying to learn about copy parameters using incremental and bulk load approach.